# jquery append writes second value from array twice

Tags: jquery, append

there is some behaviour of append I don't understand. I have an array and want to append its values to an existing table as the next column. It works, but the second value of the array is twice appended, the first is omitted. I know that an array is 0-indexed and append is 1-indexed.

```
var i = 0;
$.each(data, function(text, val) {
$(ziel).find('tr:nth-child('+(i)+')').append('<td class="rechts" width="20%">' + val + '</td>');
i++;
}
```

"ziel" is the table.
I tried different values for i, but nothing helped. All other values are appended as exspected.
Please help, Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:nth-child` is not zero-based, so `:nth-child(0)` doesn't select any element, use `:eq()` selector or `.eq()` method instead.

Comment: @BlackSheep: Thank you very much, it helped! Quite easy, but never thought of :eq() - I'm on the way to learn jQuery.

Comment: @Gabi: I try to understand why your example works while mine does'nt. Maybe because there is a $.getJSON(datei, function(data) to get the data? (datei is a filename)